# How to add Child when Parent does not have an Id yet

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, blazor-server-side

I am currently working with efcore on an Blazor Server-Side-App and run into to following Problem.

Situation is like following:

I do have a Parent, Child and Family Class which are "connected" to eachother.

```
class Parent
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
    ICollection<Child> children {get;set;}
}

class Child
{
    public int ChildId { get; set; }
    public Parent ParentId { get; set; }
}

class Family
{
    public int FamilyId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Parent> Parents {get;set;}
    public ICollection<Child> Children {get;set;}
}
```

Now I do have a Dialog where you can create a new Parent and you can also add a Child to the Parent. The Family was already created in a View before.
My Code inside the Dialog for Parent and Child looks like this:

```
@code {

    private Parent parent;
    private Family Family;
    ICollection<Family> families;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
        families = await context.families.ToListAsync();
        Family = families.FirstOrDefault();
    }

    void CreateParent() 
    {
        parent = new Parent();
        parent.Family = Family;
    }

    void AddChildToParent()
    {
        Child child = new Child();
        child.Family = Family;
        parent.children.Add(child);
    }

    void Save()
    {
        using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
        context.Parents.Update(parent);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

When i try to save this, then EFcore throws an InvalidOperationException: The Instance of entity type "Family" cannot be tracked because another instance is already beeing tracked.

What am i doing wrong?

Btw. Code ist just pseudo

Comment: Do you assign `Family` field anywhere?

Comment: try adding AsNoTracking() in 
context.Parents.AsNoTracking().Update(parent); this might help you

Comment: it doesn't help... already tried

Comment: You are using two instances of `DbContext`. One in `OnInitializedAsync` where you fetch `Family` entity and the other in `Save` when you save parent. Once you exit `OnInitializedAsync` method, your `Family` entity is detached from context, so when you try to save `Parent` EF thinks you want to add `Family` as well which already exists. Either use one instance of `DbContext` or attach `Family` entity in `Save` method.

Comment: @StefanGolubović thanks for your reply. I thought the DbContext is only short living because of the using statement and therefore the tracking too. So i have to create a DbContext per Razor-Component or what is your recommondation for that?

Comment: The context is short-living because of the `using` statement, which is why all of the entities become detached once the context is disposed. I never worked with Razor so I'm not sure what's the best practice here, but I guess [it doesn't hurt to create context when your need it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/dbcontext-configuration/#the-dbcontext-lifetime) - in your case per component.

Comment: @StefanGolubović thanks a lot again for your explanation. I understand the problem now. I just checked the Microsoft Blazor-Sample-Projects and they also use a Context per Component if they need, so i think thats the solution! Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: Actually the code is ok and should work. But something is wrong with the model., especially `child.Parent`. It looks more like a candidate for many-to-many relationship between `Parent` and `Child` with `Family` being the "linking" entity.

Answer (score 0):

Are the instances of parent and Family in the private fields are coming from ef core and tracked?
If so, then no need to call `Update` on `Save` method, but just `context.SaveChanges();`

```
  void Save()
  {
        using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
        //context.Parents.Update(parent); omit this line
        context.SaveChanges();
  }
```

Otherwise, you can do the following:

```
void Save()
{
      using var context = DbFactory.CreateDbContext();
      context.Families.AsNoTracking.Update(Family);
      context.SaveChanges();
}
```